# How to update the value of a column to contain just the year-part of the date?

Tags: datagridcomboboxcolumn, 2-digit-year

I have a full date-time in the column `ANFISCAL`. I would like to update the column to have just the year.

I used

```
UPDATE ANIFISCALI SET ANFISCAL=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ANFISCAL)
```

but it doesn't work. I'm getting this error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

When you `extract` `year` from a `date` you are getting a `number` `datatype`.

So you are trying to `update` a column with `date` datatype with `number`.
so you are getting the error.

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER.